# gcloud beta functions deploy ha COMMAND not update HA (home automation) function URL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, actions-on-google, android-things

I stay trying do [this](https://github.com/Nilhcem/smarthome-androidthings).
(two weeks ago)

In my first gcloud beta functions deploy ha COMMAND I put XXXX project ID.
Now I stay trying put YYYY project ID, But the result only comes with XXXX project ID. Look at the photo, please.

Does anybody know how to solve this?

gcloud beta functions deploy ha issue command:

[image]

Comment: I think this goes to something within the `gcloud` interface where you associate a project identifier with each directory.

Comment: @NickFelker Hi, thanks for answering. How could I solve the problem? I've tried without --source=. but not solved

Comment: For clarification of the photo: The id project I need now is:  feiralivre-315cf

Comment: Don't know off-hand, but there should be a way to switch project ids in gcloid

Comment: I solved the issue as follows: 1)gcloud config to know my current PROJECT_ID, 2)gcloud auth login and 3 gcloud config set project PROJECT_ID, 4) gcloud beta functions deploy ha --stage-bucket staging.<PROJECT_ID.appspot.com  --trigger-http

Comment: `gcloud` maintains a set of default values including for the project. You can enumerate the list `gcloud config list` or just the project's value `gcloud config get-value project`. I keep the value unset but this requires that I specify it with every command using `--project=${PROJECT}`. You may then issue commands against multiple different projects imply by including the `--project=...` flag on the commands. You may also be authenticated with multiple account (`gcloud auth list`) and then you may specify project and accounts using `... --account=... --project=...`. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Previously stated by Neuber, this is because the correct SDK Configuration was not set properly. Just trying to expand on Neuber's comment.

1) For getting the current project ID, run the following command:

```
$ gcloud config configurations list
```

gcloud lists the configurations and shows which configuration is currently active.

2) If more than one SDK configuration was found you should choose which one would be suitable for the job. You can switch between configurations with the next instrucction:

```
gcloud config configurations activate [NAME]
```

3) If the configuration needs to set the project properly, you may use the next command:

```
gcloud config set project [PROJECT]
```

Finally you may execute the ha command in question.

For more information on this, refer to [1].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/configurations